# Excel file is not getting save in django

Tags: python, django, excel

I am importing some specific contents from excel file and saving that data to backend.
But while savinhg the uploaded excel file i am getting the error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'documents/2014/06/06/1-georgia_private_schools.xls'
```

My model.py file

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

my view.py

```
def excel(request):
    print "you in main"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "you in post"
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            print "you in"
            newdoc.save()
            newdoc = newdoc.docfile.name
            newdoc = str(newdoc)
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(newdoc)
            sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
            c = 1
            while c < len(sh.col(0)):
                first = sh.col_values(0)[c]
                second = sh.col_values(1)[c]
                c=c+1
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload.views.excel'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('property/list.html',{'documents': documents, 'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am getting error for the line wb = xlrd.open_workbook(newdoc)

Please help me out for this. There might be a problem in path which i am providing to save the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
import os

from django.conf import settings

path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, newdoc)
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
```

Comment: so i need to put this in view. So there is no need fo model,,,,,,na?